# Silverlight app won't load in any browser

Tags: silverlight

The silverlight app wont load in any browser. The outline is there when highlight the area.
Here's the code

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" class="content" style="border-style: none">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="400" height="200">
        <param name="source"value="http://www.shortwavelog.com/ClientBin/RCSRemote.xap" />
        <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.60129.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="initParams" value="Mode=Mini" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60129.0" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
         style="border-style: none" />
    </a>
    </object>
        <iframe id="Iframe1" style='visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; border: 0px'>
        </iframe>

</div>
```

This isnt my app its from a website and its created by someone else.

Comment: Works fine when I paste your code into a html page and run it on a web server. I get the silverlight app in my browser. How are you running the web page?

Comment: Im just putting it in a normal html page

Comment: I don't know what im doing wrong

Comment: How are you accessing the page? Are you hosting it somewhere or just opening it on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're going to need to host this page on a website. See the relevant information [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/238545/590950.aspx/1?Loading%20remote%20XAP%20from%20local%20HTML%20file) and [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/06/10/troubleshooting-debugging-silverlight-cross-domain-xap-hosting.aspx).

> The second issues is one of hosting Silverlight applications (XAPs) on your site that are from a different domain.  What I mean here is that your site (www.coolwebapp.com) has an  tag for Silverlight plugin that has the Source parameter set to apps.anothersite.com/foo.xap.  This is essentially the cross-domain hosting situation.  What happens in this situation is that the plugin loads but the app does not, presenting in just a big blank space where the app should be.

Since the app loads fine when I host it on a site I would assume you're hitting some kind of cross-domain error going from file:// to http://

I was also able to just download the [xap file](http://www.shortwavelog.com/ClientBin/RCSRemote.xap) referenced in the object tag and then put that file in the same directory as the html page and it worked.

```
<param name="source"value="RCSRemote.xap" />
```

So you can try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just for informational purposes in case other people are getting similar problems:

Check if the Startup Project is set to the .Web side of the Solution and not to the Silverlight part.

This occurs for example when your toying around with OOB: Enabling OOB will set the Silverlight side as the startup Project, than disabling OOB will not change it back for you to the .Web side.

Comment: Just FYI this wasn't in a Silverlight project, just a static html file in the file system opening using the file protocol.